# Use yii2 session in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, session, yii2

I put yii2 framework in seprate directory at root of Wordpress directory. But now I want to make single login for both. How can I use yii2 session in wordpress or how can I do single login for both?

Comment: $_SESSION array must work in both sites

Comment: yes it works. But I want to know How can I get user identityClass info in wordpress.

Comment: you need init yii2.

try something like 

`defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);

require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/config/yii.php');

new yii\web\Application($config);`

Comment: If you have found a solution to your problem please post the answer.

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis We drop this idea, We made a simple cms plugin in yii2 framework itself and use it.

Comment: @ManuJain thank you very much for your response!